# Why "\n" does not work in TextView for strings obtained from API in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, textview

I have a string which I obtained the value from API. String has \n to make TextView multine. But it does not work.

For example;

The string is "Stack \nOverFlow".
Expected result:
Stack
OverFlow

Real Result
Stack \nOverFlow

I added string to resource file.;

%1$s

Than put it into textView in Fragment;
Lets say the string I obtained from API is; stackOverFlowText = "Stack \nOverFlow"

binding.stackOverFlowText = getString(R.string.stack_over_flow, stackOverFlowText)

What is the solution?

Comment: Use `replaceAll("\\n", "\n")` to replace all `\n` character sequences with newlines.